Differential algebraic equations with nested Piecewise seems not solvable for sympy.solve()?
currently I am trying to use sympy to help me derive differential algebra equations from OpenModelica(a physical simulation tool). A similar example can refer to pymoca. The physical model is not the point so it can be ignored.
In short, I have a python class that reformulates a physical model by sympy which is shown below:
from __future__ import print_function, division
import sympy
import sympy.physics.mechanics as mech
from sympy import sin, cos, tan, Piecewise

class OdeModel:
    def __init__(self):
        self.t = sympy.symbols('t')
        self.x = sympy.Matrix([])
        self.u = sympy.Matrix([])
        self.y = sympy.Matrix([])
        self.p = sympy.Matrix([])
        self.c = sympy.Matrix([])
        self.v = sympy.Matrix([])
        self.x0 = {}
        self.u0 = {}
        self.p0 = {}
        self.c0 = {}
        self.eqs = []
        self.f = None
        self.g = None

    def compute_fg(self):
        n_states = len(self.x)
        n_vars = len(self.v)
        n_inputs = len(self.u)
        n_outputs = len(self.y)
        n_eqs = len(self.eqs)
        lhs = list(self.x.diff(self.t)) + list(self.v) + list(self.u) + list(self.y)
        fg_sol = sympy.solve(self.eqs, lhs, dict=True)
        fg_sol = fg_sol[0]
        self.f = self.x.diff(self.t).subs(fg_sol)
        self.g = self.y.subs(fg_sol)

class NonlinearRC_circuit(OdeModel):
    def __init__(self):
        super(NonlinearRC_circuit, self).__init__()

        # states
        C__v = mech.dynamicsymbols('C.v')
        self.x = sympy.Matrix([C__v])
        self.x0 = {
            C__v : 0.0
            }

        # variables
        ground__p__v, ground__p__i, C__p__v, C__p__i, C__n__v, C__n__i, C__i, nonlinearResistor__v, nonlinearResistor__p__v, nonlinearResistor__p__i, nonlinearResistor__n__v, nonlinearResistor__n__i, nonlinearResistor__i, sineVoltage__v, sineVoltage__p__v, sineVoltage__p__i, sineVoltage__n__v, sineVoltage__n__i, sineVoltage__i, sineVoltage__signalSource__y = mech.dynamicsymbols('ground.p.v, ground.p.i, C.p.v, C.p.i, C.n.v, C.n.i, C.i, nonlinearResistor.v, nonlinearResistor.p.v, nonlinearResistor.p.i, nonlinearResistor.n.v, nonlinearResistor.n.i, nonlinearResistor.i, sineVoltage.v, sineVoltage.p.v, sineVoltage.p.i, sineVoltage.n.v, sineVoltage.n.i, sineVoltage.i, sineVoltage.signalSource.y')
        self.v = sympy.Matrix([ground__p__v, ground__p__i, C__p__v, C__p__i, C__n__v, C__n__i, C__i, nonlinearResistor__v, nonlinearResistor__p__v, nonlinearResistor__p__i, nonlinearResistor__n__v, nonlinearResistor__n__i, nonlinearResistor__i, sineVoltage__v, sineVoltage__p__v, sineVoltage__p__i, sineVoltage__n__v, sineVoltage__n__i, sineVoltage__i, sineVoltage__signalSource__y])

        # constants
        self.c = sympy.Matrix([])
        self.c0 = {
            }

        # parameters
        C__C, nonlinearResistor__Ga, nonlinearResistor__Gb, nonlinearResistor__Ve, sineVoltage__V, sineVoltage__phase, sineVoltage__f, sineVoltage__signalSource__amplitude, sineVoltage__signalSource__f, sineVoltage__signalSource__phase, sineVoltage__signalSource__offset, sineVoltage__signalSource__startTime, sineVoltage__offset, sineVoltage__startTime = mech.dynamicsymbols('C.C, nonlinearResistor.Ga, nonlinearResistor.Gb, nonlinearResistor.Ve, sineVoltage.V, sineVoltage.phase, sineVoltage.f, sineVoltage.signalSource.amplitude, sineVoltage.signalSource.f, sineVoltage.signalSource.phase, sineVoltage.signalSource.offset, sineVoltage.signalSource.startTime, sineVoltage.offset, sineVoltage.startTime')
        self.p = sympy.Matrix([C__C, nonlinearResistor__Ga, nonlinearResistor__Gb, nonlinearResistor__Ve, sineVoltage__V, sineVoltage__phase, sineVoltage__f, sineVoltage__signalSource__amplitude, sineVoltage__signalSource__f, sineVoltage__signalSource__phase, sineVoltage__signalSource__offset, sineVoltage__signalSource__startTime, sineVoltage__offset, sineVoltage__startTime])
        self.p0 = {
            C__C : 0.3,
            nonlinearResistor__Ga : 1.1,
            nonlinearResistor__Gb : 1.3,
            nonlinearResistor__Ve : 0.3,
            sineVoltage__V : 1.0,
            sineVoltage__phase : 0.0,
            sineVoltage__f : 1.0,
            sineVoltage__signalSource__amplitude : 1.0,
            sineVoltage__signalSource__f : 1.0,
            sineVoltage__signalSource__phase : 0.0,
            sineVoltage__signalSource__offset : 0.0,
            sineVoltage__signalSource__startTime : 0.0,
            sineVoltage__offset : 0.0,
            sineVoltage__startTime : 0.0
            }

        # parameters
        self.u = sympy.Matrix([])
        self.u0 = {
            }

        # outputs
        self.y = sympy.Matrix([])

        # equations
        self.eqs = [
            sineVoltage__n__v - (ground__p__v),
            sineVoltage__n__v - (C__p__v),
            nonlinearResistor__n__v - (C__n__v),
            sineVoltage__p__v - (nonlinearResistor__p__v),
            sineVoltage__n__i + C__p__i + ground__p__i,
            nonlinearResistor__n__i + C__n__i,
            sineVoltage__p__i + nonlinearResistor__p__i,
            ground__p__v,
            C__i - (C__C * (C__v).diff(self.t)),
            C__p__i + C__n__i,
            C__i - (C__p__i),
            C__v - (C__p__v - C__n__v),
            # nonlinearResistor__i - nonlinearResistor__Ga * nonlinearResistor__v,
            nonlinearResistor__i - (Piecewise((nonlinearResistor__Gb * (nonlinearResistor__v + nonlinearResistor__Ve) - nonlinearResistor__Ga * nonlinearResistor__Ve, nonlinearResistor__v < (-nonlinearResistor__Ve)), (nonlinearResistor__Gb * (nonlinearResistor__v - nonlinearResistor__Ve) + nonlinearResistor__Ga * nonlinearResistor__Ve, nonlinearResistor__v > nonlinearResistor__Ve), (nonlinearResistor__Ga * nonlinearResistor__v, True))),
            nonlinearResistor__p__i + nonlinearResistor__n__i,
            nonlinearResistor__i - (nonlinearResistor__p__i),
            nonlinearResistor__v - (nonlinearResistor__p__v - nonlinearResistor__n__v),
            sineVoltage__signalSource__y - (sineVoltage__signalSource__offset + Piecewise((0.0, self.t < sineVoltage__signalSource__startTime), (sineVoltage__signalSource__amplitude * sin(6.283185307179586 * sineVoltage__signalSource__f * (self.t - sineVoltage__signalSource__startTime) + sineVoltage__signalSource__phase), True))),
            sineVoltage__v - (sineVoltage__signalSource__y),
            sineVoltage__p__i + sineVoltage__n__i,
            sineVoltage__i - (sineVoltage__p__i),
            sineVoltage__v - (sineVoltage__p__v - sineVoltage__n__v)
            ]
        
        self.compute_fg()

model = NonlinearRC_circuit()
print(model.f)

In compute_fg(), it solves the equations by fg_sol = sympy.solve(self.eqs, lhs, dict=True), however, for this example, the return value of fg_sol is a empty list and the solve run for a long time. I had tried some simpler examples and there is no problem, so I doubt that the reason is because there exists a nested Piecewise() relationship between
nonlinearResistor__i - (Piecewise((nonlinearResistor__Gb * (nonlinearResistor__v + nonlinearResistor__Ve) - nonlinearResistor__Ga * nonlinearResistor__Ve, nonlinearResistor__v < (-nonlinearResistor__Ve)), (nonlinearResistor__Gb * (nonlinearResistor__v - nonlinearResistor__Ve) + nonlinearResistor__Ga * nonlinearResistor__Ve, nonlinearResistor__v > nonlinearResistor__Ve), (nonlinearResistor__Ga * nonlinearResistor__v, True)))
sineVoltage__signalSource__y - (sineVoltage__signalSource__offset + Piecewise((0.0, self.t < sineVoltage__signalSource__startTime), (sineVoltage__signalSource__amplitude * sin(6.283185307179586 * sineVoltage__signalSource__f * (self.t - sineVoltage__signalSource__startTime) + sineVoltage__signalSource__phase), True)))

If we want to solve nonlinearResistor__i  than we need nonlinearResistor__v, but nonlinearResistor__v  is based on sineVoltage__signalSource__y  and thus the first equation has a Piecewise() in another Piecewise().
Questions:

Does nested Piecewise() that cause these equations not solvable?
How should I modify to fix this problem?

If there is anything unclear, please tell me, thank you.
As I said, I have tried some simpler examples and there is no problem, so I doubt that the reason is because there exists a nested Piecewise() in the equations
